# Can I Add Logic within Laravel Route?

Tags: php, laravel

So in my Laravel app, I want to pass in a parameter to a named route and then also have logic (a couple if statements) so I can return specific functions from a controller. I know the below syntax isn't correct, but I want to do something like the below

```
Route::get('profile', function(){
    if(Config::get('constants.ORG_ID') === 'organization'){
        [
            'as' => 'profile',
            'uses' => 'ProfileController@index'
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a [route middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware) so you can determine the next redirect.

```
Route::get('profile', [
    'as' => 'profile', 
    'middleware' => ['organization']
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use middleware which is appropriate, donot write logic in route file, otherwise you will end up with issues when deploying application and if you want to cache routes ;)